# Product of random elements

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am reading a book by Billingsley (convergence of probability measures) and he makes a footnote on page 27 which I am struggling to understand. I'll explain the setup below.

Suppose $(X_n,Y_n)$ are random elements of $S\times S$, where $S$ is a metric space. Then since the projections $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ are continuous, we have that $X$ and $Y$ are random elements of $S$.

The footnote says that the reverse implication ($X_n$ and $Y_n$ random elements of $S\implies$ $(X_n,Y_n)$ random element of $S\times S$) holds if $S$ is separable, but not in complete generality. This is what I am struggling to understand. I can't see where separability would be used here.

If we take a measurable set $A\times B\subset S\times S$ and look at the inverse image wrt $(X_n,Y_n)$, we just get $(X_n^{-1}(A),Y_n^{-1}(B))$ which is measurable by measurability of $X_n$ and $Y_n$. Since such measurable sets form a generating $\pi$-system of the product $\sigma$-algebra, this should conclude the result. However I haven't used any notion of separability here, so I am assuming I am mistaken somewhere.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau $ be the metric topology and let $\mathcal{S}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e., $\mathcal{S}=\sigma (\tau )$). Then, $\mathcal{S}\times \mathcal{S}\subset \sigma (\tau \times \tau)$, but it is not true that $\mathcal{S}\times \mathcal{S}=\sigma (\tau \times \tau)$ in general. Hence, if $X$ and $Y$ are random elements, then $(X,Y)$ is $\mathcal{S}\times \mathcal{S}$-measurable, but not $\sigma (\tau \times \tau )$-measurable in general. If $S$ is assumed to be separable, $\mathcal{S}\times \mathcal{S}=\sigma (\tau \times \tau)$. Thus, separability allows $(X,Y)$ to be $\sigma (\tau \times \tau)$-measurable. In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are random elements in a separable metric space $(S,\rho)$, then $\rho(X,Y)$ is a random variable (since $\rho:S\times S\to [0,\infty )$ is continuous and hence $\sigma (\tau \times \tau )$-measurable). In applications, separability assumption is almost inevitable to avoid the measurability considerations.